# Escaping % sign in mysqli prepare() with LIKE clause and NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, prepared-statement

## The Problem:

**Note:** NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode is ENABLED.

I am using mysqli prepared statements for querying the database. The target code is like:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mypass', 'mydb');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from `table` where `data` like ?;');
```

Now, let's say I manually(from mysql client, not from php) insert 3 records which have the literal values of `JDxDD`, `JD_DD` and `JD\DD`:

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `data` = 'JDxDD';
INSERT INTO `table` SET `data` = 'JD_DD';
INSERT INTO `table` SET `data` = 'JD\DD';
```

Now, consider this:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ?;');
$key = 'JD_DD';
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $key);
$stmt-> execute();
```

This returns *all 3 rows*, as expected. Now, I want to just select the one with value `JD_DD` (i.e. exclude the `JDxDD` and `JD\DD`). So, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled), I need to *escape* the `_` using `escape` keyword to `$key = 'JD\_DD';`.

However, this:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape \'\\\';');
/*
first and last \ are for putting the ' quote,
middle 2 are for putting a \ as a part of string.
*/
```

evaluates the $stmt to be `false`, calling `$conn->error` gives this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'' at line 1

**Both of following codes give the same `Syntax error` as above:**

**(1)** I tried switching to " for encapsulating the query, as:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape '\\';");
```

**(2)** And this:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape '\';");
```

Please note that `$key = 'JD\_DD';`, while can be effectively used with (instead of `LIKE`) an `=` operator, is just an example. The `$key` can be complex such as `'JD\_D%\_X%';` or like.

## My efforts:

Here are some codes that **produces the desired output:**

**(1)** Using an *alternative escape character*:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape '|';");
$key = 'JD|_DD';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
```

This works fine as one would expect.

**(2)** *Omitting* the `escape` word altogether:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ?;');
$key = 'JD\_DD';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
```

This produces the desired `JD_DD` output. **Why??** Even with the **NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES** MODE **ENABLED**, why does `\` works as an escape character?

**(3)** The following also works:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape '\\\';");
$key = 'JD\_DD';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
```

**(4)** And so does the following:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * from `table1` where `data` like ? escape '\\\\';");
$key = 'JD\_DD';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
```

The (3) and (4) produce the *same output*. Again, **Why?**

**(5)** Also, I could turn off the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode, but that seems more like a *workaround* rather than a *solution*.

The [mariadb docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/) says:

> If you need to match the characters _ or %, you must escape them. By
>   default, you can prefix the wildcard characters the backslash characer
>   \ to escape them. The backslash is used both to encode special
>   characters like newlines when a string is parsed as well as to escape
>   wildcards in a pattern after parsing. Thus, to match an actual
>   backslash, you sometimes need to double-escape it as "\\\\".
>
> To avoid difficulties with the backslash character, you can change the
>   wildcard escape character using ESCAPE in a LIKE expression. The
>   argument to ESCAPE must be a single-character string.

Also, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924664/mariadb-bugs-like-escaping-broken) showed a bug that was fixed in MariaDB 10.1.22. I am using MariaDB 10.1.13, and that bug *is fixed* in my version. (i.e. `select 'a%b' like '%\%\%';` returns `0` *as expected*.)

I also went through [this mysql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46659).

Any help understanding the nature and origin of this issue, and/or the right way to code for `like` clause in cases where NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode is enabled, is greatly appreciated.

Also, this is my first SO question, so I have tried to be as informative and *proper* as I could be. Any critics/suggestions regarding a better way to express my question is also appreciated.

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Simply using `=` instead of `LIKE` won't help. There *may be* wildcards based on the user preferences. For example, if the user prefers to fetch *all relevant suggestions* based on his input (say `'J%D'`), then such query becomes `WHERE data LIKE '%J\%D%';`. In case when the user want to fetch *only what he typed*, I can surely use `=` in place of `LIKE`.

**Edit 2:**

Here are some tests I did:

***With NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode DISABLED***

**(1)** `INSERT INTO table set name = 'abc\def';`

this inserts `abcdef` as expected.

**(2)** `INSERT INTO table set name = 'xyz\\pqr';`

this inserts `xyz\pqr` as expected.

**(3)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'abc\def';`

this returns `abcdef` as expected.

**(4)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'abc\\def';`

this returns 0 rows as expected.

**(5)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'xyz\pqr';`

this returns 0 rows as expected.

**(6)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'xyz\\pqr';`

this returns `xyz\pqr` as expected.

**(7)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\def';`

this returns `abcdef` as expected.

**(8)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\\def';`

this returns `abcdef`. **not expected**. Isn't (8) supposed to be showing only if there are any `abc\def`?

**(9)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'xyz\pqr';`

this returns 0 rows as expected.

**(10)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'xyz\\pqr';`

this returns 0 rows. **not expected**. Isn't (10) supposed to be showing `xyz\pqr`?

***Now with NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode ENABLED***
The data inserted at (1) and (2) is also kept.

**(11)** `INSERT INTO table set name = 'abc\def';`

this inserts `abc\def` as expected.

**(12)** `INSERT INTO table set name = 'xyz\\pqr';`

this inserts `xyz\\pqr` as expected.

**(13)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'abc\def';`

this returns `abc\def` (inserted at 11) as expected.

**(14)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'abc\\def';`

this returns 0 rows as expected.

**(15)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'xyz\pqr';`

this returns `xyz\pqr` (inserted at 2) as expected.

**(16)** `SELECT * FROM table where name = 'xyz\\pqr';`

this returns `xyz\\pqr` (inserted at 12) as expected.

**(17)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\def';`

this returns `abcdef` (inserted at (1)). **not expected**. With this mode on, I would expect it to take the `\` literally (unless used with `escape = '\'`). Expected result is `abc\def` (inserted at 11).

**(18)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\\def';`

this returns `abc\def` (inserted at (11)). **not expected**. With this mode on, I would expect it to take both the `\\` literally. Expected result is 0 rows as there is no data like `abc\\def`.

**(19)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'xyz\pqr';`

this returns 0 rows. **not expected**. With this mode on, I would expect it to take the `\` literally. Expected result is `xyz\pqr` (inserted at 2).

**(20)** `SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'xyz\\pqr';`

this returns `xyz\pqr` (inserted at (11)). **not expected**. With this mode on, I would expect it to take both the `\\` literally. Expected result is `xyz\\pqr` (inserted at 12).

---

So, to conclude, the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode does in `INSERT` and `WHERE col = value` as expected - taking every `\` literally when set to ON.
BUT, with `WHERE col LIKE value` it gets strange as seen above.

For `LIKE` clauses, the `\` is *NOT taken literally* even if the mode is set to ON.

I now strongly suspect that I have misunderstood some very basic things regarding `LIKE` clauses. Any clarification is very much welcomed!

Comment: `'a%b' like '%\%\%'` _should_ return 0.  It is asking for "anything (first %) followed by _two_ percents.

Comment: What exactly is the question when your effort nr. 2 gives you the desired result? When you have `data LIKE ?` and provide `"JD\_DD"` you will get, as expected, the only row with the value `JD_DD`.

Comment: Keep in mind that NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES does not affect the values for your prepared statement, it only affects strings in your query like `SELECT 'abc\def';` (which will return "abc\def" or "abcdef" depending on your setting).

Comment: @RickJames yes, that is what I get. I wanted to say that I *don't have* this bug in my version, so my issue is originated somewhere else. My bad, I was not clear there. Edited.

Comment: @Progman _that is exactly my question_, NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES tells the parser to take the '\' character as _literal \._

But in this case, even with this mode, the \ in the passed string `JD\_DD` _is not taken literally._

Comment: @JayDadhania NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPE is only relevant for strings you create in the query, but you already have the string value as a value for the prepared statement available. See how `SELECT 'abc\def';` is affected when you enable and disable this flag. The setting has no affect when you already have the value.

Comment: @Progman I have tested some queries as you suggested, and have added the results in original question. Thank you very much for your interest!

Comment: @JayDadhania Check the note on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like. When you want to search for a `\` with LIKE you need to have `\\` in the input string, and you need to write `\\\\` to get one, when you create the string in the query. The LIKE operator has a parser as well: "[...] and again when the pattern match is made".

Comment: Thank you so much, @Progman! I added that as an answer and made it a community wiki. Much appreciated, man!

Comment: Clarification needed -- were those insert/select tests done via the commandline tool?  Or through some api (eg PHP)?

Comment: @RickJames the tests in Edit 2 are done in a Query Tab in HeidiSQL, which is same as doing in command line.

Comment: Bravo to the thorough testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 14-07-2018: (The Solution)

As @Progman's comment pointed to the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), here is the summary from the docs:

> ### Note
>
> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, `\n` to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any `\` that you use in
>   `LIKE` strings. For example, to search for `\n`, specify it as `\\n`. To
>   search for `\`, specify it as `\\\\`; this is because the backslashes are
>   stripped **once by the parser** and **again when the pattern match is made**,
>   leaving a single backslash to be matched against.
>
> **Exception:** At the end of the pattern string, backslash can be
>   specified as `\\`. At the end of the string, backslash stands for itself
>   because there is nothing following to escape.

Please do note that the above summary is for cases when NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES is **disabled**.

That said, here is **my simple understanding about this:**

The string in `LIKE` clause passes through 2 things:

(1) The Parser

(2) The Pattern Matcher

Thus, when looking for a literal `\` in ***normal mode***, we have to ***double escape*** it as `\\\\`, once for ***the parser*** and once for ***the pattern matcher***.

When looking for a literal `\` in ***NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode***, we can ***skip the escaping*** that is meant for ***the parser*** (because this mode makes *the parser* take them as *literal*), BUT we ***must escape once*** that is for ***the pattern matcher***. So, in this mode, we must use `\\` to look for a literal `\`.

**The NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode DOES NOT affect the Pattern Matcher!**

---

**To conclude:**

**(1)** for same results, the normal mode requires **2x** slashes than NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode, regardless of its use in `=` or `LIKE`. These are same:

```
SET @@sql_mode = '';
SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\\\\def';
```

and

```
SET @@sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\\def';
```

both returns `abc\def` as result.

**(2)** for same results, the `LIKE` requires **2x** slashes than `=`, regardless of its use in normal or NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode. These are same:

```
SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE 'abc\\\\def';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table where name = 'abc\\def';
```

both returns `abc\def` in *normal mode* and `abc\\def` in *NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode*.

Thanks a ton, @Progman!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `=` instead of `LIKE`??

`LIKE` should be used only when you *want* the wildcard actions of `%` and/or `_`.

**Revised case**

Requirements:

- User can enter _, %, or \ -- and the test is to take them literally, plus
- User's input is the beginning of the string

Solution 1 avoids dealing with `LIKE`:

```
WHERE LEFT(data, CHAR_LENGTH($input)) = $input
```

Solution 2 makes `LIKE` work without changing `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`:

First, quadruple each \ , second prefix each _ or % with a \ .  Then tack on `%` and do `LIKE`.

If the Requirement is that $input is to be located anywhere in `data`, then

```
WHERE INSTR($input, data)
```

Comment: Of course, that was just an example. I want to be able to query something complex like `where data LIKE 'JD\_D%\_X%';`.
The `$key` is prepared from arbitrary user input, so I need to know the proper way handling the escape etc.
Also, I can sanitize the user input to remove the special characters like `%`, but I don't want to. I want my users to be able to any literal data they want, and search/retrieve it *however they like*. Also, This is *only for learning purposes*, and I will disable the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode, but I want my application to work in correct way regardless of this mode.

Comment: @JayDadhania - Do you allow users to enter wildcards to mean wildcards?  _And_  enter the same characters to be taken literally?  Which parts of the example are escapes, which are wild, which are literal?  I know you are asking about escaping, but it is unclear what cases need escaping.

Comment: Yes, all characters coming from *the user input* needs to be taken as *literals*. For example, if the user types in `J%D`, the `%` inside it should be converted into `literal %` such as `J\%D`. I know I can achieve this by escaping, my question is regarding the `escape` clause used in prepare statement, and the *value of `escape` such as '\' or '|'`, and *why* does `J%D` need to be escaped even when NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode is *ON*. Also, with this mode, backslash *works as an escape character*, unexpected for this mode.

Comment: If there are no wildcards, use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: There *may be* wildcards based on the user preferences. For example, if the user prefers to fetch *all relevant suggestions* based on his input (say `'J%D'`), then such query becomes `WHERE data LIKE '%J\%D%';`. In case when the user want to fetch *only what he typed*, I can surely use `=` in place of `LIKE`. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @JayDadhania - Ok, then I would expect 2 or 4 backslashes to work -- it depends on how many layers of PHP the string goes through.  Each layer would cut the number in half.

Comment: you're correct. I've added this as an answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: And, apparently, `LIKE` is one of the layers that cuts in half the backslashes.